# What is the meaning of "fibers over $\Bbb S^1$"?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. I want to know what is the meaning of ''**fibers of $M$ is over $\Bbb S^1$**''? and manifolds with this property why are important? What is its relation to differential structure on $M$?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually this means that $M$ can be given the structure of a [smooth fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) over $\mathbb{S}^1$.  But it would help if you provided more context, such as where you saw this phrase.

Comment: I read it in "harmonic forms"